# Android Bluetooth (BluetoothSocket) fails to pair

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using the BluetoothChat sample as it is. However it fails while paring with a discovered device. Both devices are Samsung Galaxy Tab with Honeycomb (3.1).

It seems that the method connect of BluetoothSocket generates IOException exception. Even if I pair both of them I still have the same problem.

Thanks in advance for any help